# Blueprism after process ends, welcome program screen shows up

Tags: blueprism

I have some strange issue. I made process, that open special system, open excel read all data, close excel an process it into that system. After all, I close that system. When i start it from process studio, everything works fine. At the end, when I press "Reset" button, new "Special System" windows shows up. I absolutely dont know why.
When i start it using Control Room, it also works well but after ending each process, new "Special System" window shows up.
Could somebody help or explain why and what i am suposed to fix ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Check the Clean Up page in the object. The Clean Up page runs when the reset button is pressed as well as when a process ends, so that would explain the behavior you're seeing from Process Studio as well as when running from the control room.